# Message queue (msgget - msgsnd - msgrcv) Linux - EIDRM

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue, shared-memory

Here's my problem :
I'm trying to implement a message queue between a server and a client.
For that, i have two files, `msq-server.c` and `msq-client.c`.

I use the function `msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, &buf)` to exit the server (it does when we ask him to read the message queue 3 times, one time per second, by example).

As usual, `msqid` is set by the msgget function and buf is defined by `struct msqid_ds buf`.

The official msgctl doc says that errno is set to EIDRM (43) for the reader (the client) and I would like to display a custom error when it happens. But when I try to read a message from a closed server, the function
`msgrcv(msqid, &message, 64, 0, IPC_NOWAIT)` returns the EINVAL error. I assume that msqid is guilty

For the function `msgget`

- On the server : I use `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL |0666` flags
- On the client : I use `IPC_EXCL | 0666` flags

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

msgrcv() will return EIDRM (43) when you are reading the message queue at the time that the queue is removed via msgctl().

msgrcv() will return EINVAL (22) when you attempt to read from a message queue that no longer exists (because you removed it already ).

See the example below.

The server is started and puts one message on a queue. Then waits.

The client is started and reads the first message, then blocks waiting for the second message that never arrives.

The server removes the queue while the client is waiting for the second message and an EIDRM return code is seen.

Then the client tries to read again and since no queue is available an EINVAL is seen.

msg_server.c

```
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct msgbuf {
   long mType;
   char mText[50];
};

int main() {
   char txtBuf[50];
   int qId;
   key_t key;
   struct msgbuf msg, buf;
   struct msqid_ds msgCtlBuf;

   if ( ( key = ftok( "/tmp", 'C' ) ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "server: ftok failed:" );
      exit( 1 );
   }

   printf( "server: System V IPC key = %u\n", key );

   if ( ( qId = msgget( key, IPC_CREAT | 0666 ) ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "server: Failed to create message queue:" );
      exit( 2 );
   }

   printf( "server: Message queue id = %u\n", qId );

   strcpy( msg.mText, "This is a message" );
   msg.mType = 1;

   if ( msgsnd( qId, &msg, sizeof msg.mText, 0 ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "server: msgsnd failed:" );
      exit( 3 );
   }

   printf( "server: Message sent successfully\n" );

   printf( "server: waiting..." );
   sleep( 15 );
   printf( "server: done waiting. removing message queue...\n" );

   if ( msgctl( qId, IPC_RMID, &msgCtlBuf ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "server: msgctl failed:" );
      exit( 4 );
   }

   printf( "server: Message queue removed OK\n" );
}
```

msg_client.c

```
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct msgbuf {
   long mType;
   char mText[50];
};

int main() {
   char txtBuf[50];
   int qId;
   key_t key;
   struct msgbuf msg, buf;
   struct msqid_ds msgCtlBuf;

   if ( ( key = ftok( "/tmp", 'C' ) ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "client: ftok failed:" );
      exit( 1 );
   }

   printf( "client: System V IPC key = %u\n", key );

   if ( ( qId = msgget( key, IPC_CREAT | 0666 ) ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "client: Failed to create message queue:" );
      exit( 2 );
   }

   printf( "client: Message queue id = %u\n", qId );

   if ( msgrcv( qId, &buf, sizeof msg.mText, 1, 0 ) == -1 )
      perror( "client: msgrcv failed:" );
   else
      printf( "client: Message received = %s\n", buf.mText );

   //
   // attempt read again and block on queue waiting for server to IPC_RMID
   //
   if ( msgrcv( qId, &buf, sizeof msg.mText, 1, 0 ) == -1 )
      perror( "client: msgrcv failed:" );
   else
      printf( "client: Message received = %s\n", buf.mText );

   printf( "client: errno = %d\n", errno );

   //
   // attempt read again but message queue should now be gone
   //
   if ( msgrcv( qId, &buf, sizeof msg.mText, 1, 0 ) == -1 )
      perror( "client: msgrcv failed:" );
   else
      printf( "client: Message received = %s\n", buf.mText );

   printf( "client: errno = %d\n", errno );
}
```

./msg_server &

[1] 668

server: System V IPC key = 1124335618

server: Message queue id = 262144

server: Message sent successfully

./msg_client

client: System V IPC key = 1124335618

client: Message queue id = 262144

client: Message received = This is a message

server: waiting...server: done waiting. removing message queue...

server: Message queue removed OK

client: msgrcv failed:: Identifier removed

client: errno = 43

client: msgrcv failed:: Invalid argument

client: errno = 22

[1]+  Exit 33                 ./msg_server